# c++ convert class to boolean

Tags: c++, boolean, user-defined-types

With all of the fundamental types of C++, one can simply query:

```
if(varname)
```

and the type is converted to a boolean for evaluation. Is there any way to replicate this functionality in a user-defined class? One of my classes is identified by an integer, although it has a number of other members, and I'd like to be able to check if the integer is set to NULL in such a manner.

Thanks.

Comment: Google for "safe boolean" and you will see different solutions that allow for boolean evaluation without explicit conversion to bool, avoiding the common conversion pitfalls.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can define a user-defined conversion operator. This must be a member function, e.g.:

```
class MyClass {
  operator int() const
  { return your_number; }
  // other fields
};
```

You can also implement operator bool.  However, I would **STRONGLY** suggest against defining conversion operators to integer types (including bool) because your class will become usable in arithmetic expressions which can quickly lead to a mess.

As an alternative, for example, IOStreams define conversion to `void*`.  You can test `void*` in the same way you can test a `bool`, but there are no language-defined implicit conversions from `void*`.  Another alternative is to define `operator!` with the desired semantics.

In short: defining conversion operators to integer types (including booleans) is a REALLY bad idea.

Comment: You state that conversion to integer types is a bad idea .. but then this is exactly what your code snippet does. Agreed that `operator bool()` has unintended consequences and there are better solutions. But conversion to void* is not perfect either: `Foo x; delete x;` will now compile. `bool operator!()` is better, but you still need to do `if (!!x)` to test for the positive case. As suggested in another comment, the Safe Bool idiom is the best solution.

Comment: 1) The OP clearly did not know the syntax for defining conversion operators, otherwise he would have been able to code the most trivial solution. So he learned something new. 2) I warned him about this being a bad idea. 3) Safe bool is better, but seems like an overengineering.  If conversion to void* is good for the standard library, it's good for me too.

Comment: In C++11 there is `explicit operator bool()` (mentioned in @plats answer and @UncleBens comment) achieving what the OP wants. I think it would be good if this information would be included in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 48):

The C++11 approach is:

```
struct Testable
  {
    explicit operator bool() const
      { return false; }
  };

int main ()
  {
    Testable a, b;
    if (a)      { /* do something  */ }  // this is correct
    if (a == b) { /* do something  */ }  // compiler error
  }
```

Note the `explicit` keyword which prevents the compiler from converting implicitly.

Answer (score 10):

Simply implement `operator bool()` for your class.

e.g.

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(int x) : m_x(x) { }
    operator bool() const { return (0 != m_x); }
private:
    int m_x;
}

Foo a(1);
if (a) { // evaluates true
    // ...
}

Foo b(-1);
if (b) { // evaluates true
    // ...
}

Foo c(0);
if (c) { // evaluates false
    // ...
}
```

Comment: -1, this breaks easily in unobvious ways. Look up the "Safe Bool Idiom."

Comment: C++0x has `explicit operator bool()` to avoid implicit breakage of the kind?

Comment: @grayfade: agreed - this solution is not ideal and the Safe Bool idiom is a more robust approach.

Answer (score 5):

As others have stated, using `operator int ()` or `operator bool ()` is bad idea because of the conversions it allows. Using a pointer is better idea. The best know solution to this problem so far is to return a member (function) pointer:

```
class MyClass {
  void some_function () {}

  typedef void (MyClass:: * safe_bool_type) ();
  operator safe_bool_type () const
  { return cond ? &MyClass::some_function : 0; }
};
```

Answer (score -2):

C++ checks if the statements result is whether equal to zero nor not. So i think you can define equality operator for your class and define how your class will be different from zero in which conditions.

Comment: Not really... the value is converted to a boolean. It is just that in general the conversion is done from `0` to `false` and from anything else to `true`. The important difference is that if you define `bool operator==( type const&, int );` and `bool operator==( int, type const & );` you can compare your object to `0` but you cannot use the object as a condition.